# Is there a PPA for having nvidia-cuda-toolkit with the latest cuda (11.1) for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal)?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

The official packages do not seem up-to-date (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nvidia-cuda-toolkit) but using the latest cuda seems to matter when using newer hardware.

Nvidia is making packages available, but there is no guarantee that they will work well or will integrate with Ubuntu's management of nvidia drivers.

Is there an effort to create an ubuntu package in a PPA so we do not have to install manually and work out conflicts individually? (the package would handle that)

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: @N0rbert - Thanks for the reply. I edited the question to clarify that this is about the absence of PPA, not about why a released Ubuntu isn't chasing the latest release of software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open the terminal and remove any NVIDIA traces that you may have on your system.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*
   sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
   sudo apt-get remove --autoremove nvidia-*
   ```
2. Setup the correct CUDA PPA on your system.

   ```
   export DISTRO=ubuntu2004
   export ARCHITECTURE=x86_64
   sudo apt update
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
   sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/${DISTRO}/${ARCHITECTURE}/7fa2af80.pub 
   sudo bash -c "echo deb\ http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/${DISTRO}/${ARCHITECTURE}/\ / > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list"  
   sudo bash -c "echo deb\ http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/${DISTRO}/${ARCHITECTURE}\ / > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda_learn.list"
   ```
3. Install CUDA 11.1 packages.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt -y install cuda-11-1
   sudo apt install libcudnn8
   ```
4. Specify the PATH to CUDA in the '.profile' file. Open the file by running `sudo nano ~/.profile` and add the following lines at the end of the file:

   ```
   # set PATH for cuda 11.1 installation
   if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin/" ]; then
       export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
       export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
   fi
   ```

   Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
5. Restart with `sudo reboot` and check the versions of the installation.

   CUDA:

   ```
   nvcc  --version
   ```

   NVIDIA driver:

   ```
   nvidia-smi
   ```

   libcudnn:

   ```
   /sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed ‘s/:/ /’ <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) 2>/dev/null | grep libcudnn
   ```

Comment: Thanks. In step 2, the lines to add to the `.list` repos file seem incorrect. There should be a space before the `/` at the end of the line, no?

Comment: Still in step 2, the step `sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys ...` does not seem to fetch any key.

Comment: I fixed both by editing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks karel for the answer. In step 2 I faced a GPG error: "public key is not available".

I followed the comment of jtran1999 in the nvidia issue [1632](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1632) to proporly add the key and the CUDA PPA. Maybe it'll help others with the same error:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update
```

Then continued for step 3 and everything worked fine!!