# How to install Cuda Toolkit Version 11.1 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, cuda

I am trying to install cuda toolkit version 11.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 because a neural network I'm using is only compatible with cuda version 11.1, however, the latest version is 11.3. Is there anyway I can install version 11.1 (Haven't installed cuda yet, nvidia driver: 460.73.01).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a PPA for having nvidia-cuda-toolkit with the latest cuda (11.1) for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292120/is-there-a-ppa-for-having-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-with-the-latest-cuda-11-1-for-ub)

Answer (score 0):

Pick the Nvidia driver you really want (465 is available from the standard repositories if you select it from Software and Updates/additional drivers).
Make a cuda11.1 directory somewhere writable by you, make a bin and lib directory under it. Get the 11.1 .run file from Nvidia, skip any offers of an Nvidia driver, and override the system locations with your ...cuda11.1/bin and ...cuda11.1/lib directories.  Add the cuda11.1/bin to the start of your PATH, and the cuda11.1/lib to the beginning of your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  That's it.  No sudo needed when you execute the run file, and you can add links to any old versions of programs cuda11.1 might need in your cuda11.1/bin directory.  No old/odd program/lib versions need be installed in your system areas.

Terrance has a nice answer for details on using the .run file for CUDA installation.  It is easy to have multiple CUDA versions available to you, just change your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This method avoids the dependency problems with the Nvidia .deb files. and Nvidia drivers.